# Post photo using Tumblr

Tags: ios, tumblr

For tumbler integration, I am using tumblerSDK for iOS. I have to post image on tumbler so I am referring PhotoPostApp example in SDK. There are some parameters that I need to fill up for the below code.

I got the OAuthConsumerKey and OAuthConsumerSecret but from where I can get OAuthToken and 
OAuthTokenSecret?

```
[TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthConsumerKey = @"";
[TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthConsumerSecret = @"";
[TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthToken = @"";
[TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthTokenSecret = @"";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to your -> [tumblr api console](https://api.tumblr.com/console//calls/user/info)
2. Enter your Consumer Key and Consumer Secret
3. Grant access
4. Click the button with "SHOW KEYS"
5. Get your Auth Token and Auth Secret from that :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `authenticate:callback:` on `[TMAPIClient sharedInstance]` will kick off the three-legged OAuth flow to retrieve the token and token secret.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to hold on to the OAuthToken and the OAuthTokenSecret for that user.  It will reset to nil when the app is reset and has to launch again.